# What is that matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ be given by its [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) $G$. Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a linear operator with $\mathop{\rm rank} A=k$ (We denote its matrix also by $A$.). What is the matrix of the orthogonal projector from $ \mathbb{R}^n$ on $ \ker A$?

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could present the answer? The question is not easy.

Comment: Please, don't convert the simplectic-linear-algebra tag  to the  linear algebra tag.

Comment: That's kind of a mistake.  I misread that as symplectic. But I still add the tags linear algebra (which will increase your question's visibility)

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gepctewxcflubf/OP.pdf?dl=0) is the answer done with Maple in the case $n=4,\, k=2$ and the  standard inner product. I think Mathematica can do it in the general case.

Comment: Please, don't "imrove" my spelling.  I know where the point should be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We minimize $(x-a)^t G (x-a)$ for some fixed $a$ and $x\in\ker A$. Let $N$ be a matrix whose columns form a basis of $\ker A$. Then, we can equivalently minimize $(Nu-a)^t G (Nu-a)$ for every $u$. The unique minimizer is given by $N^t G (Nu-a) = 0$ or $u = (N^t G N)^{-1} N^t G a$.

The projection matrix is then $N (N^t G N)^{-1} N^t G$, which is obviously not zero.

--

Notice that the range of $G^{-1}A^t$ is orthogonal to kernel of $A$ and has a basis given by the columns of $G^{-1}A^t$. So the projection of the range would be $G^{-1}A^t (AG^{-1}A^t)^{-1} A$ and of its orthogonal complement would be $I - G^{-1}A^t (AG^{-1}A^t)^{-1} A$.

--

For $x\in\ker A$ we have $x^t G G^{-1} A^t = 0$. That is, the kernel of $A$ is orthogonal to range $G^{-1}A^t$. By a dimension argument, the kernel is in fact the orthogonal complement.

Comment: @ user251257 : Does $\cdot ^t$ denote transposition? As far as I understand it, you reformulate the question to "How to find that matrix $N$?", not answering it.

Comment: You can use standard linear algebra techniques to N like Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @ user251257 : Could you elaborate that? The explicit answer in terms of $A$ and $G$ is required.

Comment: @  user251257 : Can you base your added statement "Notice that the range of $G^{−1}A^t$ is orthogonal to kernel of $A$ "? BTW, I don't see any Gaussian elimination in your answer.

Comment: Gaussian Elimination would not give you an explicit for formulae like you want.

Comment: I used a calculus argument to get the projection matrix. You could also translate the proof for the Euclidean inner product. Which would be purely algebraic.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach: once again, we take $N$ to be a matrix whose columns form a basis of $\ker A$.  Let $G^{1/2}$ denote the positive definite square root of $G$.

Note that the columns of $G^{-1/2}$ form an orthonormal basis with respect to the inner product.  Call this basis $\mathcal B$. The columns of the matrix $G^{1/2}N$ are the column-vectors of $N$, rewritten relative to $\mathcal B$.

By the formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas), we can write the matrix of the projection relative to $\mathcal B$ as
$$
[P_N]_{\mathcal B} = [G^{1/2}N]([G^{1/2}N]^T[G^{1/2}N])^{-1}[G^{1/2}N]^T
= G^{1/2}N(N^TN)^{-1}N^TG^{1/2}
$$
The projection relative to the original basis is then given by
$$
P_N = G^{-1/2}[P_N]_{\mathcal B}G^{1/2} = 
N(N^TN)^{-1}N^TG
$$

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom : I vote up your answer. Unfortunately, the green tick is unique.